Drag and Drop a generated file (e.g. MIDI) from a Pyside6 or Qt Application to another application (like a DAW)
I would like to write a simple Qt app (in Python with PySide6) that will generate a midi file such that the user can drag it directly into their DAW (e.g. Reaper, Ableton, Bitwig).
I have got
  def mousePressEvent(self,e):
    if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
      drag = QDrag(self)
      mimeData = QMimeData()
      mimeData.setData("audio/midi",mid)
      drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
      drag.exec(Qt.CopyAction)

in my mousePressEvent, and this seems to get halfway there: Reaper reacts as if a MIDI file is being dragged over. But what do I do next so that the MIDI arrives in Reaper when I release the drag?

What is the content of mid? There are various mime types, and there is no absolute convention AFAIK. In theory, the data should be the raw data of a "mid like" file content, there are some modules that are capable of writing such contents using an abstraction of the midi structure, therefore you can set the data of the mime accordingly using a QByteArray starting from the bytes.

For now it is the content of an actual midi file. That is: mid = open("sample.mid","rb").read()

I changed it to mimeData.setData("audio/midi",QByteArray(mid)) but still no clip appeared when dropping into Reaper.

Are you completely sure that the generated file is a valid SMF file? Also, if the file gets actually generated and saved to disk, another solution would be to just set the file path into the mime data, using setUrls().

I generated the midi data by creating a clip in Reaper, exporting that to a .mid file, and then using that as a placeholder for midi I intend to create. I can drag the file into reaper from Explorer and it works. The code above, dragging text (i.e. setText, not setData) into notepad works. So I'm trying to figure out how to do things that aren't text.

When you drag a file from Explorer, you don't actually the file contents, but the file path (which is what setUrls() does).

With Reaper and Ableton at least, and on Windows at least, it is necessary
to create a temporary file, write the data there, and attach a file url
to the mime object: with Reaper and Ableton, the data can be an empty QByteArray. My mistake is assuming that Reaper would read the MIDI from the
data sent as part of the mime object. Bitwig refuses to accept the dragged file though the e.mid file can be successfully dragged from the file explorer, and with above code, midi can be dragged to the explorer and then from the explorer into Bitwig successfully, so I don't know what's going on there.
The following works:
import tempfile
...
  def mousePressEvent(self,e):
    if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
      drag = QDrag(self)
      # we must have delete=False as the file must persist long
      # enough for Reaper to read from it, and it must be closed
      # before Reaper can read from it (on Windows at least)
      with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".mid",delete=False) as f:
        fn = f.name
        f.write(mid)
      temp_filenames.append(fn)
      mimeData = QMimeData()
      mimeData.setData("audio/midi",QByteArray(""))
      # Reaper and Ableton get their data from the file named in the url
      # not from the data in the mime object
      urls = [ QUrl.fromLocalFile(fn) ]
      mimeData.setUrls(urls)
      drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
      dropAction = drag.exec(Qt.CopyAction)

# list of temp files we have created to clear up on exit
# it makes more sense to have a class manage creation of these
# temporary files, writing their contents, and cleaning up at exit
# time.
temp_filenames = []


Drag and drop is always managed by the program, so it's the programmer's responsibility to eventually support certain data. As explained above, when dragging from Explorer, only the path to the selected file or folder is actually set on the drag data (which makes sense: you imagine you start dragging a 4gb file by mistake). In theory, actual d&d of midi data is possible, but now it's clear that Reaper doesn't support it. It's understandable: 1. while mid files are normally small, they can theoretically be very big; 2. in order to proper support external drop of midi data, the program then »

» should open the content of the data (to verify it's actually MIDI), but that content may be too big or invalid, so they probably chose to ignore it; this is probably because, normally, the d&d of MIDI contents is done within the same program. Note that this also means that you probably don't need to actually set the audio/midi format with an empty array: setting the url of the temp file with the correct extension should be enough for reaper to accept it. It's also probably unnecessary to keep a list of files: you can assume that if a new drag starts, the previous one has been completed.
